# How to get Instagram API Access Token

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, instagram-api

How can I get the access token for instagram API after creating an app in the developer console? As I want to perform hashtag search for one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register and fill the form on Instagram's Api Request Site:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/